# Mysql split column string into three rows

Tags: mysql, sql

This query

```
SELECT user_Id,CAST(leave_dates_object AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8) AS LeaveDates 
FROM `lms_leaves`
```

returns

[image]

Now I want three rows user_Id and Date and F_or_H from the formatted string return from leave date.

I modified and tried [code from this link](http://www.marcogoncalves.com/2011/03/mysql-split-column-string-into-rows/) but can't able to get result.

Expected Output

```
user_Id Date    LeaveType
85  2016-09-06  F
85  2016-09-07  F
85  2016-09-06  H
63  2016-03-25  F
63  2016-03-02  F
63  2016-03-03  H
```

Please Help me.

Comment: You want the date, it looks like some values of LeaveDates have more than one date - which date do you want?

Comment: i want user_id, Date, LeaveType(F or D) for every date resides in LeaveDates.

Comment: could you show an example of what you want your output to be?

Comment: Can you change the table design?

Comment: should the second row in your expected output have the date 2016-09-07?

Comment: question updated that was mistack.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have maximally 8 dates in one record:

```
create table users (userId int not null, leaveDates varchar(1000) not null);

INSERT users (userId,leaveDates) VALUES (85,'--- \r-2016-09-06:F\r-2016-09-07:F'),(85,'---\r-2016-09-06:H'),(63,'---\r-2016-03-25:F'),(63,'---\r-2016-03-02:F\r-2016-03-03:H');

SELECT s.userId AS userId,LEFT(s.leaveDate,CHAR_LENGTH(s.leaveDate)-2) AS ldate, RIGHT(s.leaveDate,1) AS lflag
FROM (
  SELECT 
    u.userId, 
      REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(u.leaveDates, '\r-', n.number),
         CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(u.leaveDates, '\r-', n.number -1)) + 1),
         '\r-', '') as leaveDate
  FROM (SELECT u0.userId,REPLACE(u0.leaveDates,'---','') AS leaveDates FROM users u0) u
  INNER JOIN (SELECT 1 AS number UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8) n
  ON (char_length(u.leaveDates) - char_length(replace(u.leaveDates, '\r-', '')) >= n.number-1)) s
 WHERE s.leaveDate<>''
 ORDER BY userId,ldate,lflag;
```